# Need to remove newlines from object/embed tags only using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, newline, nokogiri

I need to remove newlines from any object/embed tags. I am currently attempting to do so using Nokogiri by doing the following:

```
s = "<div>
<object height='450' width='600'>
<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
<param name='movie' value='http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1'>
<embed src='http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowscriptaccess='always' height='450' width='600'>
</embed>
</object>
</div>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(s)
doc.css('object').each { |o| o.inner_html.gsub!(/\n/, ""); puts o.inner_html }
```

Please note that the example is for object tags only.

Printing o.inner_html at the end of the block shows that no replacement has occurred, even though the gsub text appears correct. Also, once that part is resolved, I need to make sure that the actual *object* node in the *doc* object is saved with the updated values.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: a) I would remove the whitespace via `doc.xpath('//object/text()').each{ |t| t.remove }`; b) Doing this does not help; c) Even if you remove the whitespace between params in your source, you'll see it appear in the output. The problem is with the serialization, not the document representation.

Comment: doc.xpath('//object/text()') returns nothing in this example.

Comment: "doc.xpath('//object/text()') returns nothing in this example". Actually it does. It returns `[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80899cb8 "\n">]`

Comment: Must have mistyped something, it sure does.

Comment: Still doesn't answer my questions above, though.

Comment: I killed my answer as it wasn't helpful (sorry) so I'm commenting here instead. Phrogz is right, the newlines are being added by Nokogiri's serialization so it doesn't matter what you set `.inner_html` to. Nokogiri doesn't appear to have any options for suppressing newlines. Sorry, you probably need to write your own serialization if you don't new newlines. Why does it even matter anyway? The browser won't care about the newlines, why do you?

Comment: Normally it doesn't matter, but in this case, I'm also using BBRuby to parse BBCode on the page, and it converts newlines to <br /> tags, even ones that appear inside object/embed tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it!

```
require 'nokogiri'
s = <<ENDHTML
<div>
<object height='450' width='600'>
  <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
  <param name='movie' value='http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1'>
<embed src='http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowscriptaccess='always' height='450' width='600'>
</embed>
</object>
</div>
ENDHTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(s)
doc.css('object,embed').each{ |e| e.inner_html = e.inner_html.gsub(/\n/,'') }
puts doc.serialize( save_with: 0 )

#=> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
#=> <html><body><div>
#=> <object height="450" width="600"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1"><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3317924&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" height="450" width="600"></embed></object>
#=> </div></body></html>
```

1. Removing all text nodes does not fully clean the document; you need to use the `inner_html`.
2. Calling `inner_html.gsub!` is not the same as `inner_html = inner_html.gsub`.
3. As shown, you need to use `serialize` with the hash `:save_with => 0` passed in to prevent Nokogiri from *generating* newlines between tags in the output.

Comment: Works great - you rock, sir! Only slight change I made was to change the last line to `puts doc.css('body').children.first.serialize(:save_with => 0)` in order to avoid printing the doctype, html, and body tags.

Comment: FYI - `save_with: 0` should be changed to `:save_with => 0` in the code area above. Thanks again.

Comment: @modulaaron Sorry, that's the 1.9 Hash syntax with symbol keys; yes, for 1.8.x you'll need that syntax.